# How can i use ng-repeat on a JSON data that have numbers as key of it?

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to use ng-repeat to display the table of data 
that provide by JSON format like this

```
{"name":"Aruba","code":"ABW","1960":54208,"1961":55435},
{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"AFG","1960":8774440,"1961":8953544}
```

But my code below seems doesn't work with {{ country.1961 }}.

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Country name</td>
        <td>1960 population</td> 
        <td>1970 population</td>
        <td>1980 population</td> 
        <td>1990 population</td>
        <td>2000 population</td> 
        <td>2010 population</td>
        <td>Percentage growth between 1960 and 2010</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ country.1961 }}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
```

When i delete `<td>{{ country.1961 }}</td>` everything works fine.
How can i fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{country.1961}}` works fine for me check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwz78oxa/)**, 
but its better you can use **bracket notation** instead of dot notation when

- keys are fully numbers like '1985'
- keys contains spaces like 'My Place'

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w4rvgf7/)**

```
 <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>Country name</td>
            <td>1960 population</td>
            <td>1970 population</td>
            <td>1980 population</td>
            <td>1990 population</td>
            <td>2000 population</td>
            <td>2010 population</td>
            <td>Percentage growth between 1960 and 2010</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
            <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ country['1961'] }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes you are right, but each times it improves the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use backet notation `{{country['1961']}}`.

Comment: I think, it's go a comment, not a answer ;)